# Ruby on rails mailer + Mailgun marked as spam

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailgun

I have a ActionMailer with following settings(according to [this](http://blog.mailgun.com/post/tips-tricks-avoiding-gmail-spam-filtering-when-using-ruby-on-rails-action-mailer/) guide):

```
require 'digest/sha2'
class WinnerMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Resque::Mailer
  default "Message-ID"=>"<#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(Time.now.to_i.to_s)}@my-domain.com>"
  default from: "mail@my-domain.com"
```

My email has:

```
From: mail@my-domain.com
To: xxx@gmail.com
Message-Id: <50117ee0355959752a01b1737c8568f30ea72db2f35ec68cfa7808cea18dbb69@my-domain.com>
```

My `production.rb` has following settings:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = :true #try to force sending in development
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = :false
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :authentication => :plain,
      :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "my-domain.com",
      :user_name => "postmaster@my-domain.com",
      :password => "qqqqq"
  }
```

For some reasons all my letters go to spam folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending the email `from: mail@my-domain.com`?

Comment: @uhn-nohn I'm not sure what you mean, but I think yes. I have a domain (not my-domain.com of course) and my site is there.

Comment: Why I was asking that. It is possible to get your emails sent to spam, because your domain is `my-domain.com` and the sender is again `mail@my-domain.com`. Have you tried sending them with a gmail account?

Comment: @uhn-nohn No, I haven't tried with gmail. When I was trying to send mail with sandbox everything was ok (domain was `sandboxBlaBlaBla.com` and from was `me@sandboxBlaBlaBla.com`).

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of different reasons, why your mail might be marked as spam. Just a few examples:

- based on the wording (blacklisted words, too short),
- the domain is on a blacklist,
- the IP is on a blacklist,
- the receiver once marked your mail as spam
- you sent too many emails in a short period of time
- you recently change domain or IP
- IP does not match domain name
- number of recipients
- ...

Some spam filters add a description to the mail header why the mail was marked as spam and how the mail scored in different spam checks. You might want to take a lock the header to get more information.

Furthermore, you might need some help from the company that manages your mail server, to find out if your domain or IP is on a list of hosts known for spam. People who manage mail servers usually have access to such lists and monitor list entries for the customers and may take actions against wrong listings.